# I dont know how to write check - if element is on the website

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

i am coding in C# with Selenium. Problem

We have user A - admin and user B - no-admin

On the page there are two button and user A can see two buttons but user B only one

In my soruce code i write something like this:

```
bool X = Utils.FVE(pk.PrintXpath);
            Assert.AreEqual(true, X);

bool Y = Utils.FVE(pk.AssignPKXpath);
            Assert.AreEqual(false, Y);
```

my method is

```
public static bool FVE(string xpath)
        {

            if (driver.FindElements(By.Id(xpath)) != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

for X button it is ok true is ture but for Y button i still get true... which should be false. I have no idea how to fix this...

Comment: In the function `FVE` (please avoid abbreviation), you can write `return driver.FindElements(By.Id(xpath)) != null)`

Comment: What are the values of `pk.PrintXpath` and `pk.AssignPKXpath`?

Comment: they are just `public string examplename = "//*[@id='exampletext'";` when i changed to `return driver.FindElements(By.Id(xpath)) != null)` it work like my longer version :P

It always returing true which means even if he dont find element still it is not null i guess i need to rewrite this `!= null` thing

Comment: Why is your string called `xpath` whilst you use a `By.Id` method? In the above example, you can just use the Id `exampletext`, and stay away from XPaths. (Xpaths are prone to errors like forgetting a closing square bracket).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindElements` always returns a `List<IWebElement>`. In case nothing is found, the list is empty and not `null`. Do something like:

```
public static bool FVE(string xpath) 
    => driver.FindElements(By.Id(xpath)).Any();
```

It will return `true` if one or more elements are found, otherwise `false`.